# Heroku credentials popup in pycharm

Tags: heroku, deployment, pycharm, ide, heroku-postgres

I keep getting  a "Log In to git.heroku.com" popup in PyCharm in one repo:

[image]

How should I get rid of this popup? I hit cancel every time as I don't remember password and don't want to use this anymore.

Comment: What do you do when this pops up? Are you adding your password and leaving "Remember" checked? Hitting "Cancel"?

Comment: I hit cancel everytime as I didn't remember password and dont want to use this anymore

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because the repository has a [Git remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) that points to the Git service that powers [Heroku's push-to-deploy functionality](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).

That remote is normally called `heroku`, but it might have a different name. You'll need to remove it. There might be multiple Heroku remotes that need to be removed.

### CLI

First, list your remotes by running

```
git remote -v
```

You should see your configured remotes listed, e.g.

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/your-app.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/your-app.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:github/your-app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:github/your-app.git (push
```

In this case, we have two remotes: one called `heroku` that points to `https://git.heroku.com/your-app.git` and one called `origin` that points to a repository on GitHub.

Remove each of the remotes that points to Heroku (has `git.heroku.com` in its URL), e.g.

```
git remote rm heroku
```

### GUI

I don't use PyCharm, but here's what [the documentation says](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/set-up-a-git-repository.html#add-remote):

> To remove a repository that is no longer valid, right-click it in the [Branches pane of the Git Log tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/log-tab.html#BranchesPane), and select **Remove Remote** from the context menu.

As above, the remote is probably called `heroku` but may have a different name. Look at the target URL to see if it contains `git.heroku.com`.